# iPhone App Navigation Tabbed Bar button images and background very delayed in appearing

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I have an iPhone app with a custom vertical Navigation Tab Bar and it work fine through most of the app but in one area the tab bar background image and tab button images are missing then appear about 15 seconds later. The touch events where the buttons should be are working fine instantly but the images are just very delayed in appearing. Can't figure out why this is happening and only in this area, have been trying to figure this out for a very long time. Thanks.

Comment: Did u check whether the function is getting called from thread other than main thread? Because, lot of times, we can see the delay in appearance of UI when called from another thread or it may crash as well. Make sure you always do UI tasks on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code, it will be easer to help.

The best way to solve problems with navigaton bar, is to have a method that sets the navigation bar in the correct view that you are in, and make shure you call this method at the "viewWillApear".
Call the method for example "navigationBarSetup", and set there all the correct buttons, and views for the navigation bar.

This Essie is happening because you have some delayed view blocking your buttons.

Oh and try cleaning (command + k) before you run next time. Is could be the problem some times..

Hope this helps